# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function. react router v4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am rather new to reactjs and was testing basic server side rendering with react-router **v4** but I cannot get past this error, been trying since hours. I have tried every solution that I found on google but none of them seems to be working.

Here is the server.js code :

```
import Express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import MyRoutes from './routes/routes.js';

...

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  let markup = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">        
    <body>
        ${renderToString(<StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}><MyRoutes/></StaticRouter>)}
    </body>
    </html>`;
  res.write(markup);
  res.end();
});
```

Problem seems to be with the following code :

**./routes/routes.js code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Match, Miss } from 'react-router';    

const componentTest = () =>
(       
    <div>
     Testing a component
    </div>
);

export default () => (
        <div>
        <Match exactly={true} pattern="/" component={componentTest} />
        </div>
);
```

Now **if I remove the Match tag line I get blank page with no error.**
But if that Match tag line is there I get the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
    in Unknown
    in Router (created by StaticRouter)
    in StaticRouter
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `StatelessComponent`.
    at invariant (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:44:15)
    at instantiateReactComponent (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:74:56)
    at instantiateChild (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js:44:28)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js:71:16
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:77:5)
    at traverseAllChildren (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:172:10)
    at Object.ReactChildReconciler.instantiateChildren (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js:70:7)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:187:41)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:226:27)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:653:32)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the latest version of react-router v4, `Match` has been replaced with `Route`. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route
Try to use `Route` instead of `Match`

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara That worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was given by [Tharaka Wijebandara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036138/tharaka-wijebandara) in comments.

Problem is that `Match` has been replaced by `Route` in `react-router v4`. So replacing the `Match` tag line with this line solved it :

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={componentTest} />
```

Source : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route